# Finding an invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP$ is a Jordan matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab

Find an invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP$ is a Jordan matrix.

Is there a way in matlab to find such a matrix $P$ given $A$?

Comment: See http://de.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/jordan.html

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich is there any way to find it by hand?